# NumPy: summing over function values using ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

statistician here trying to figure out how NumPy works on the fly. I need to implement something using SciPy's `rv_discrete`, but I'm getting errors which I've traced back to the following behavior in NumPy. It's probably super basic, but I'm seriously confused.

I'm trying to understand why the following simple code **doesn't** work:

```py
import numpy as np

def testfn(k):
    if k == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1/k**2

def sumtest(k):
    m = np.arange(1,k+1)
    print(np.sum(testfn(m),axis=0))

sumtest(100)
```

If I simply get rid of the conditional statement inside `testfn()` and replace it with `return 1/k**2` then everything is fine. I can intuit that this is because inside `sumtest()` I am passing an *ndarray* object to `testfn()`, but I can't get a grasp for what is going on under the hood when that happens.

The reason I ask this is that this is *exactly* how `_cdfsingle()` is coded in SciPy's `rv_discrete` class, and I need to know how that works to define new random variables.

If this is too basic, then I'd appreciate a link to somewhere to get started. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Per the comment below, let me clarify what I want to happen. I basically want `testfn()` to act as if it operates componentwise on the array which is passed to it. So if `[1,2,3]` is the array passed to `testfn()`, then at the end of the day I want  `np.sum` to return the quantity `1 + 1/4 + 1/9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Numpy.sum()` requires an array-like as its first argument. As such, you'll need `testfn()` to return an array.

It seems like you think `Numpy.sum()` will evaluate `testfn()` on each input before summing it. That's not the case. If you were to map `testfn()` over `m`, you might get the behavior you're looking for.

So try:

```
n = map(testfn, m)
print(np.sum(n,axis=0))
```

Comment: I guess with Numpy you have to use `np.vectorize()` instead of `map`, but this essentially does the trick. I will try it on my full-scale example first to see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

*Most* `numpy` functions at element-wise on arrays.  Your desired functionality could be done in several ways.  The most numpythonic is probably to change `testfn(k)` to the following:

```
# This already works element-wise on k.
# Numpy overrides the basic mathematical operators like +, -, *, /, **
# to be element-wise.  Therefore `result` is an array the same length as k
# (Remember to use 1. so float division occurs!)
result = 1. / k**2 

# result[k == 1] is equivalent to result[np.where(k == 1)]
# for this example, only the first element of k is equal to 1
# so the [k == 1] yields "index 0"
# therefore result[k == 1] yields only the first element of result
# once you've selected the appropriate elements of result, overwrite 
# the values with whatever you like
result[k == 1] = 1

return result
```

Now you will always get an array returned from `testfn`, and you have fine-grained control over the values in that array.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that k is an array so that's why the conditional statement isn't working, but I guess I'd like to know how to *make* it work. And I'm not trying to avoid division by zero, I'm just interested in understanding how things work behind the scenes!

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to test by the conditional statement `if k == 1`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I'm trying to build a component-wise operation. So if a component of the array being passed to `testfn()` is equal to 1 (which will always be the first component in this case, I guess), then map that to 1. For all other values `k` inside the array (i.e. >1), map those to `1/k**2`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Since `1/(1^2) == 1`, why do you need to do this check?

Comment: This all goes back to how `rv_discrete` works. I'm working with a complicated pmf in reality, and it requires this sort of control which I can't get around analytically. I just came up with this simplified example to avoid getting bogged down in notation.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand now.